# Which characters are allowed in an SNMP OID?

Tags: snmp, asn.1, mib

I'm writing a custom MIB file and was wondering which characters I can use in textual object identifiers (OIDs), ie. in the strings that make up identifiers like `iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifIndex`.

It looks like only alphanumeric characters and hyphens are allowed. Also, two consecutive hyphens are forbidden as well (because they start a comment in a MIB file). But what are the exact rules, and where is that stated in the standard(s)?

Comment: FYI this is about SMI, not ASN.1 (and not, directly, SNMP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RFC documents for SMI contain clear descriptions on such entities, like

> For the purposes of this    specification, an ASN.1 module name
> begins with an upper-case letter    and continues with zero or more
> letters, digits, or hyphens, except    that a hyphen can not be the
> last character, nor can there be two    consecutive hyphens.

[Reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#page-12)